# @Html.Widget Not Support in View Page load from plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I have load some pages from  Plugin, But `"@Html.Widget"` Code Not support on view page, If I use This `@Html.Widget` On View page then it's return error:-

```
 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Nop.Plugin.mode.xxxxx>' does not contain a definition for 'Widget' and no extension method 'Widget' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Nop.Plugin.model.xxxxx>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can any one suggest me am i missing some thing?

Regards,
Vinit Patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following line of code to the top of your cshml file

```
using Nop.Web.Framework;
```

Comment: i have add this line but it's not work, see this view page is load from plugin

Comment: it works for me. i have view page in my plugin. check that that widget defined in Nop.Web.Framework - maybe it is custom widget from other plugin